# Javascript countdown and countup timer based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and was playing around a bit with timers. I found code for a countdown timer based on test field input [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67631-Timer-with-an-input-text-box), and I tried adding a countup timer to the same page, but it's not working.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div id="countup"></div>
<div id="notifier"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer() {
  userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
    if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(!userInput.match(numericExpression)){
      alert("Please enter a number")
    } else {
      var countuptime = 0;
      function display( notifier, str ) {
          document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
      }

      function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
        return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
      }

      function setTimer( remain, actions, countuptime ) {
          (function countup() {
              display("countup", toMinuteAndSecond(userInput - countuptime));
              (countuptime+= 1) <= userInput && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
           })();
           (function countdown() {
               display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
               actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
               (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
            })();
      }

      setTimer(userInput, {
         10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
          5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
          0: function () { display("notifier", "Time is up");       }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="startTimer()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I tried creating a new variable (countuptime) that starts at 0 and goes up until it's is the same as userInput, at which point it should stop. However, when I try to test, the count up timer displays NaN:NaN. I'm trying to stay away from JQuery right now and get the basics of Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you defined "setTimer" function you set 3 parameters but when you invoked it you provided two arguments.That's why the third argument 'countuptime' remained undefined. Also you don't have to delete countuptime value from userInput. Check this out:-

```
    <html>
<body>
<div id="countup"></div>
<div id="notifier"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer() {
    userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
    if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(!userInput.match(numericExpression)){
      alert("Please enter a number")
    } else {
      var countuptime = 0;
      function display( notifier, str ) {
          document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
      }

      function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
        return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
      }

      function setTimer( remain, actions, countuptime ) {
          (function countup() {
              display("countup", toMinuteAndSecond(countuptime));
              (countuptime+= 1) <= userInput && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
           })();

      }

      setTimer(userInput, {
         10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
          5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
          0: function () { display("notifier", "Time is up");       }
      }, countuptime);
    }
  }
}
</script>
Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="startTimer()" />
</body>
</html>
```